# Where is svn db file?

Tags: svn

I create repo use below command.

```
svnadmin create ./repo/big_repo
svn checkout file:///repo/big_repo
cd big_repo && dd if=/dev/zero of=500MB bs=1m count=500
svn add 500MB && svn commit -m "big file"
```

I check the loca file size use `du -m big_repo` is 1001MB, but why repo/big_repo remote repo not any file change?

Where's svn db file store? tks

Answer (score 0):

Look in `big-repo/db` directory. For example, `big_repo/db/revs/0` will contain changes revision by revision (do not expect 500MB changes, though - it will be compressed).